# Есть скрипт, который срабатывает, когда блок(элемент) полностью виден на странице. Как сделать так, чтобы этот скрипт отрабатывал с разными блоками?

Tags: javascript, php

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

#console {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #666;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: #fff;
}

.block {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #ececec, #bfbbbb);
  padding: 100px 0;
  font-size: 44px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.tsr_test {
  display: block;
  height: 280px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.tsr_test .image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tsr_test img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.tsr_test .title {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tsr_test p {
  text-indent: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tsr_test:hover {
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
```

```html
<div id="console"></div>

<div class="block">Content</div>
<div class="block">Content</div>
<div class="block">Content</div>
<script>var block_show = null;

function scrollTracking(){
    var tsr_id = 67;
    var stri = 'tsr_id='+tsr_id;
    var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var et = $('#67').offset().top;
    var eh = $('#67').outerHeight();
    
    if (et >= wt && et + eh <= wh + wt){
        if (block_show == null || block_show == false) {
            $.get('/postback/views.php', (stri), function(data) { 
            console.log(data); // ответ от сервера
        });
        }
        block_show = true;
    } else {
        block_show = false;
    }
}

</script>
<div class="tsr_test">
    <a href="">
        <div class="image" id=67>
            <img src="/img/tsr/5fcf9cfee7383.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="title"><p>
            текст
        </p></div>
    </a>
</div>
<script>var block_show = null;

function scrollTracking(){
    var tsr_id = '68';
    var stri = 'tsr_id='+tsr_id;
    var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var et = $('#68').offset().top;
    var eh = $('#68').outerHeight();
    
    if (et >= wt && et + eh <= wh + wt){
        if (block_show == null || block_show == false) {
            $.get('/postback/views.php', (stri), function(data) { 
            console.log(data); // ответ от сервера
        });
        }
        block_show = true;
    } else {
        block_show = false;
    }
}


    $(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollTracking();
});
    
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    scrollTracking();
});
</script>
<div class="tsr_test">
    <a href="" >
        <div class="image" id=68>
            <img src="/img/tsr/5fcf9cfee7383.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="title"><p>
            текст
        </p></div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="block">Content</div>
<div class="block">Content</div>
<div class="block">Content</div>
```

Comment: Срабатывает только последний скрипт(

Comment: Ну по логике он и должен срабатывать=) Вы функцию перезаписываете=)

Comment: @Walfter я решил это, назвав функции по разному, но теперь 1 скрипт отправляет 1 запрос, а другой отправляет запросов 20 (get)

Comment: Наверное потому что один каждый раз при скроле срабатывает а другой при загрузке документа